# Extjs 5.1 Ipad Safari TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data["id"]')

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, safari, extjs5

I use `Extjs 5.1` with crisp touch theme.I works fine on chrome mobile , but in safari it doesn't.In console i have this error any ideas?Thanx in advance.

`Extjs 5.1` iPad Safari T

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data["id"]')`

Answer (score 0):

The bug is related to the Example Calendar Code. If you look at the [calendar example page](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/calendar/index.html) on the iOS Simulator, you get the same bug.

After investigating some more, the stacktrace indicates that

```
/ext/examples/calendar/src/form/field/ReminderCombo.js
```

is where the problems are. It seems to have something to do with the loading of the records.

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this issue and spent quite a bit of time with Sencha Support trying to track it down. As of late February 2015 they told me that it has been fixed in the 5.1 nightly builds - if you're a support subscriber this would be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the latest Nightly build (ext-5.1.1.308) worked. The calendar-app works again, for us.